# Функция main в статической библиотеке

Tags: c, library, компоновщик, ld

Собираю статическую библиотеку, в которую попадает функция main, находящаяся в одном из исходных файлов. Вопрос в следующем: почему при сборке другого исходного файлов с функцией main и библиотекой не возникает ошибка компиляции из-за множественного определения?

Comment: А она не объявлена со слабым связыванием? Если нет, то должна быть ошибка. А вообще функцию main не размещают в статической библиотеке.

Comment: А когда программа запускается, то какая из двух функции main выполняется?

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду `weak`, то нет. Да, Вы правы, так получилось случайно. Но возник вопрос, почему это сработало.

Comment: Выполняется main, который в `.c` файле. То есть библиотечный не запускается., хотя `objdump` утверждает, что функция `main` в библиотеке действительно существует.

Comment: Может библиотека написана на c++? Плюсовые компиляторы могут по-своему преобразовывать имена.

Comment: Все написано на Си и компилируется `gcc` с использованием таких флагов: `-c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11`

Comment: Множественное определение функции c внешним связывайнием в программе является неопределенным поведением.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибки компиляции быть не может, в каждой единице трансляции только одно определение функции `main` что совершенно законно. Вопросы возникают во время компоновки. А компоновщик работает просто: если в коде остался не разрешенный символ, он просматривает доступные библиотеки и добавляет первое найденное определение. В результате получается программа на `C` которая не содержит неопределённого поведения - определения всех функций на этапе компоновки разрешаются однозначно.

*NB: Cтандарт считает сборку с множественными определениями неопределённым поведением. То что в моих примерах и у вас получаются работающие программы - определяется тем как работает конкретный компоновщик в конкретной операционной системе. В нормальной разработке такого быть не должно.*

Иллюстрация:

```
// f1.c --------------------------------------
int f() { return 1; }


// f2.c --------------------------------------
int f() { return 2; }


// main.c ------------------------------------    
#include <stdio.h>

int f();

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", f());
}
```

Подготовка:

> ```
> $ ls
> f1.c  f2.c  main.c
>
> $ gcc -c -o f1.o f1.c
> $ ar r libf1.a f1.o
>
> $ gcc -c -o f2.o f2.c
> $ ar r libf2.a f2.o
>
> $ gcc -c -o main.o main.c
>
> $ ls
> f1.c  f1.o  f2.c  f2.o  libf1.a  libf2.a  main.c  main.o
> ```

Результат зависит от порядка библиотек в командной строке. Компоновщик выбирает первый подходящий символ не проверяя его уникальность:

> ```
> $ gcc main.o -L. -lf1 -lf2
> $ ./a.out
> 1
>
> $ gcc main.o -L. -lf2 -lf1
> $ ./a.out
> 2
> ```

Ваша ситуация другая: функция `main` уже определена в одном из объектных файлов и в библиотеке. Проделаем тоже самое для функции `f`. Компоновщик не заглядывает в `libf2.a` - нет необходимости:

> ```
> $ gcc main.o f1.o -L. -lf2
> $ ./a.out
> 1
> ```

Ошибка возникнет только если оба определения будут в объектных файлах, не в библиотеках. Такие символы компоновщик обязан собрать все:

> ```
> $ gcc main.o f1.o f2.o
> f2.o: In function `f':
> f2.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `f'
> f1.o:f1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

P.S. [Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/fat-zer) подсказал простой способ диагностировать множественные определения в библиотеках. Пара ключей `-Wl,-whole-archive`/`-Wl,-no-whole-archive` вокруг библиотек заставляет компоновщик включать все символы из библиотек (не только необходимые):

> ```
> $ gcc main.o -L. -Wl,-whole-archive -lf1 -lf2 -Wl,-no-whole-archive
> ./libf2.a(f2.o): In function `f':
> f2.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `f'
> ./libf1.a(f1.o):f1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Comment: как вариант, «чтобы была ошибка» можно добавить `-Wl,-whole-archive`, но это, конечно, способ кувалды...

Comment: Спасибо @Fat-Zer ! Отличная кувадла.

Comment: Но, вообще-то подобное переопределение часто используется для переопределения реализации библиотечных функций

Comment: Да, и это работает пока вы абсолютно уверены в том как компоновщик собирает программу.